# TYPO3: How can I post required login data for fe_login via curl?

Tags: curl, authentication, typo3-7.6.x

I have created a protected page and I have added some protected files. The file protection is done by the extension "fal_securedownload". So a frontend user have to be logged in to get the files and a frontend user need access to the files. This is working great by default.

Furthermore I have created a extension which should dynamically generate a zip-archive with accessible files for each frontend user. For this reason I need to pass the frontend user data of the user which is logged in via curl, but how can I do something like this?

My collect function looks like the following:

```
protected function collectFile($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return($result);
}
```

and the relevant code for the file collecting looks like this:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $downloadFile = $this->collectFile($file);
    DebuggerUtility::var_dump($downloadFile);
}
```

as you can see I just try to get the file by url. This urls will be automatically generated by "fal_securedownload" and looks like this:

```
http://example.com/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=3&token=8cfae76eae5b13ad01e83031f52208c988f80940
```

so there is nothing special and I got the following message for each file:

```
Extbase Variable Dump
'Authentication required!' (24 chars)
```

This message will be generated by the extension "fal_securedownload" and is completely ok, because curl currently dont know about the authorization data, so how can I pass the login data of the currently logged in frontend user to curl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to trigger an HTTP request for a particular front-end user or front-end user-group. In that regard you need to take care about the session transfer or the login process if the session is not existing yet.

### Request method

However, you can use the front-end user simulation that is used in the TYPO3 AdminPanel as well. This component defines `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->simUserGroup` and allows one preview contents for a particular user-group. You can either make use of that using your eID script or an accordant hook in `TypoScriptFrontendController` (TSFE). Having a look to the following methods might be helpful in your scenario:

- [`TypoScriptFrontendController::initFEuser()` & "initFEuser" hook](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-4-0/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php#L1025)
- [`TypoScriptFrontendController::determineId()` & `$this->simUserGroup` property](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_8-4-0/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php#L1243)

The current session ID can be retrieved from `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->id`. An alternative to forward the session as cookie in the custom cURL request might be the usage of the `ftu` parameter which holds the session hash (see [TSref documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#ftu) for further details).

**In general transferring the user session to some external system or using insecure transportation (e.g. non-HTTPS connection) is a potential attack vector to your application since it might disclose information and thus allow session hijacking by anyone. Please consider this in terms of web application security.**

### Retrieval method

However, since you seem to have full access to the database already, the round-trip via the front-end rendering process looks superfluous to me.
A better way would be to collect and aggregate the files in your domain model already and resolve the permissions there. Using the front-end rendering process just delegates the interpretation and query part to some other controller.

If you're using the plain TYPO3 core, you just have to evaluate the database tables `tt_content` and `sys_file` (if system extension `filemetadata` is installed) concerning front-end permissions in the table field `fe_groups`.

Comment: Hi oliver, thx for your reply and yes this is what I want to do. I think you are right and the round-trip via the frontend rendering process is superfluous, because if a frontend user is logged in then he has already access to the files, too. But I want that the user has also the opportunity to dynamically select all the files which he want to download. So I want to deliver a zip archive which is done be a custom selection. I could also use JavaScript for this part, but I have read that this will be not so great for big files or it could make problems with browsers like ie.

Comment: So maybe my approach is just wrong, because I dont know how I can create a zip archive by a set of TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File.

Comment: I think I can create the zip archive via server related paths. So my approach was just wrong, but thank you for your great answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is open developer tools, load the page that is accessible only to the logged in user and then copy the link in the network tab via 'Copy as cURL' right-click menu item. What this will do is copy into your clipboard a curl command that contains everything that needs to be sent to TYPO3 for it to allow access to a user only accessible page. From this you can easily customize it to be able to generate that same curl command for every logged in user.